# Rails searchkick cannot get results based on where query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, searchkick

I'm using Searchkick on my Event model in my app. I'm trying to search results only where status: "published". I'm testing this in the console and so far I know there is an event with "Quiz". I get one result back. I can check to see the results showing that status: "draft". However when I try to write this query into the result to confirm the results count it is just not taking the status: "draft" into consideration and bringing me back 1 result. Below is the code I'm using and the results from search kick. As per the documentation I cannot see where I'm going wrong.

```
results = Event.search "quiz"
```

response:

```
=> #<Searchkick::Results:0x00007feb0a2d57d8 @klass=Event(id: integer, title: string, content: text, category_id: integer, user_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, slug: string, status: integer, featured: boolean, recommended: boolean, excerpt: text, sold_out: boolean, ticketsolve_url: string, meta_title: string, meta_description: text, ticketsolve_event_id: string, featured_video: string, show_video: boolean, author_name: string, expiry: date, manual_seo: boolean, price_details: text, remove_booking_button: boolean, tags: string), @response={"took"=>4, "timed_out"=>false, "_shards"=>{"total"=>5, "successful"=>5, "skipped"=>0, "failed"=>0}, "hits"=>{"total"=>1, "max_score"=>41.952984, "hits"=>[{"_index"=>"events_development_20181122112141928", "_type"=>"event", "_id"=>"3", "_score"=>41.952984}]}}, @options={:page=>1, :per_page=>10000, :padding=>0, :load=>true, :includes=>nil, :model_includes=>nil, :json=>false, :match_suffix=>"analyzed", :highlight=>nil, :highlighted_fields=>[], :misspellings=>true, :term=>"quiz", :scope_results=>nil, :index_name=>nil, :total_entries=>nil}>
```

results.total_count is equal to 1 which is correct.

results.[0] shows this event.

response:

```
=> #<Event id: 3, title: "It's A Table Quiz! 2018", content: "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html>\r\n<head>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n...", category_id: 10, user_id: 2, created_at: "2018-09-20 12:57:01", updated_at: "2018-11-07 19:15:29", slug: "it-s-a-table-quiz-2018", status: "draft", featured: false, recommended: false, excerpt: "On October 4th get yourself and three of your smar...", sold_out: false, ticketsolve_url: "https://firstfortnight.ticketsolve.com/shows/87359...", meta_title: "First Fortnight Event Title", meta_description: "First Fortnight Event Description", ticketsolve_event_id: "1111111", featured_video: "", show_video: false, author_name: nil, expiry: "2019-01-18", manual_seo: false, price_details: nil, remove_booking_button: false, tags: nil>
```

We can see the status is "draft". So now i'm going to try search using Quiz and also where status equals "draft" to try get a result of 1.

```
results = Event.search "quiz", where: {status: "draft"}
```

result count is equal to 0.

I've also tried other variations of status: 1 or status: :draft but these bring back no results. Plus seeing the results above I presume the correct search is where: {status: "draft"} anyway.

I'll add my model code just in case I've done something stupid. Any help would be great thanks.

model:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
    extend FriendlyId

    # Search kick with callback so that when data is committed search runs reindex
    searchkick callbacks: :async
    # Controlled data that is indexed. Allows the user to find posts by author.
    def search_data
    {
            title: title,
            stats: status,
            content: content,
            excerpt: excerpt,
            tags: tags,
      author_name: user.name
    }
  end

    enum status: {draft: 0, published: 1}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upon reading over it again and checking I wasn't going mad I noticed a bloody typo in the model. Results work fine now console. Thanks.